# Pandas: Grouping rows by one of several indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, grouping

I am trying to generate a list of distinct people from a table that includes person names and several other weakly-identifying columns. I am assuming that if the name and one other column are equal, then the rows refer to the same distinct person. For example, if two rows each have 'John Brown' as the name, they could well be referencing two separate people that share that name, but if two rows have 'John Brown' as the name **AND** '123' in Column A, then I'm assuming they are referencing the same 'John Brown'. The same is true for the columns B and C.

- Row Id
- Person Name
- Column A
- Column B
- Column C
- PersonId (added after grouping)

After generating the list of distinct people, I want to insert a column into the original table indicating the PersonId of the distinct individual to which that row refers.

My question is: does Pandas have a clean, efficient way to group with a condition like this? Two rows are in a group if [Name, Column A] are equal **OR** [Name, Column B] are equal **OR** [Name, Column C] are equal.

In general, I'd like to know if this falls into a certain family of common data science operations.

Comment: Why don't you provide a sample input and output instead of writing such long description?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems like you are grouping duplicates together.

You can simply drop the duplicates using:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Followed by assignment of personal ID.